# Mathematical induction 5

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Given that $$x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdots x_n=1$$  prove that $$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n \ge n$$

So I solved this for $x_1=x_2=x_3=\dots=x_n=1$
but for  $$x_1 \cdot \frac{1}{x_1} \cdot x_2 \cdot \frac{1}{x_2} \cdots x_n \cdot \frac{1}{x_n}?$$
I don't know what to do I tried to check the assumption for $n=1$ but for $n=1$ you got $x_1=1$ and if I'm checking for $n=2$ I'm getting $x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}\ge 2$
and I don't know how to go from there...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the AM-GM inequality (AM is the Arithmetic Mean and GM is the Geometric Mean), it says that if $x_1,\cdots,x_n\geq 0$ then $$\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2,\cdots x_n}\leq\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}.$$

Using this you can easily solve your problem.